# How to load UI with escaping closures and async calls?

Tags: swift, asynchronous, escaping, closures, api-design

I've written a function called 'configureLabels()' that is supposed to make a 'GET' request and retrieve a value which is then supposed to be set as the text for a label. The request is async so I thought I would be able to use an escaping closure to update the UI when the request is finished being made. I'm relatively new to coding, so I am not sure what I've done wrong. I'd really appreciate anyone's help in figuring this out.

This is the code containing the 'configureLabels()' method:

```
import UIKit
```

import SwiftyJSON

class ItemDetailViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var numberOfFiberGrams: UILabel!

var ndbnoResults = [JSON]()
var ndbno = ""

let requestManager = RequestManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    configureLabels()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


func configureLabels() {

    requestManager.ndbnoRequest(ndbno: ndbno) { (results) in
        let json = JSON(results)
        let fiber = json["food"]["nutrients"][7].dictionaryValue
        for (key, value) in fiber {
            if key == "value" {
                self.numberOfFiberGrams.text = "\(value.stringValue)"
            } else {
                self.numberOfFiberGrams.text = "Fail"
            }
        }
    }
}

/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/
```

}

And here is the code containing the function that 'configureLabels()' calls:

```
    func ndbnoRequest(ndbno: String, apiKey: String, completionHandler: @escaping (_ results: JSON?) -> Void) {
    Alamofire.request("https://api.nal.usda.gov/ndb/V2/reports?ndbno=\(ndbno)&type=f&format=json&api_key=\(apiKey)", method: .get).validate().responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let value):
            let json = JSON(value)
            completionHandler(json)
            print("successful ndbno request")
        case .failure(let error):
            completionHandler(nil)
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happened? App closes? Nothing happened?

Comment: The label is not updating with the data retrieved from the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks ok only issue I have find with your code is you are not calling the `completionHandler` in `failure` part, You need to always call completion block so it will gave you idea have you got response or not as of your `completionHandler` argument is type of `[JSON]` as of your not having response in `failure` part you are not calling `completionHandler` in it. What you can do is make it `optional` and call `completionHandler` with `nil` argument in case of `failure`.

```
func ndbnoRequest(ndbno: String, completionHandler: @escaping (_ results: [JSON]?) -> Void) {
    let parameters = ["api_key": "tIgopGnvNSP7YJOQ17lGVwazeYI1TVhXNBA2Et9W", "format": "json", "ndbno": "\(ndbno)"]
    Alamofire.request("https://api.nal.usda.gov/ndb/reports/V2", method: .get, parameters: parameters).responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let value):
            let json = JSON(value)
            let ndbnoResults = json["foods"].arrayValue
            completionHandler(ndbnoResults)
            print("successful ndbno request")
        case .failure(let error):
            completionHandler(nil)
            print("error with ndbno request")
        }
    }        
}
```

Now call it this way and wrapped the optional in completion block so you can confirm you get response.

```
requestManager.ndbnoRequest(ndbno: ndbno) { (results) in
    if let result = results {
        let json = JSON(result)
        let fiber = json["food"]["nutrients"][7].dictionaryValue
        for (key, value) in fiber {
            if key == "value" {
                self.numberOfFiberGrams.text = "\(value.stringValue)"
            } else {
                self.numberOfFiberGrams.text = "Fail"
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        print("Problem to get response")
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Nirav, thank you very much for your response. I updated my code with your suggestions and the label still does not update. I checked the IBOutlet as well. Any ideas for what the issue could be?

Comment: @BenNalle Are you sure that you are getting `response` try once printing results in completion block

Comment: I wasn't getting a response, but after I fixed that the label would still not load. It turns out there were two problems, I wasn't getting a response and I parsed the JSON incorrectly so I wasn't retrieving a value as I subscripted through it with SwiftyJSON. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Everything related to UI must be **ALWAYS** done on the main thread.
So try this:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    let json = JSON(results)
    let fiber = json["food"]["nutrients"][7].dictionaryValue
    for (key, value) in fiber {
        if key == "value" {
            self.numberOfFiberGrams.text = "\(value.stringValue)"
        } else {
            self.numberOfFiberGrams.text = "Fail"
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. I agree with Nirav about *failure callback* - you should handle it too. And I strongly recommend you to give functions and vars more readable and meaningful names, not "ndbnoRequest" and "ndbno". You won't remember what does it mean in few weeks :)

Comment: Thank your for your help. It is working now. There were two problems I wan't getting a response and I parsed the JSON in correctly.